# How to return a value from a function which was passed another function (with arguments) as an argument? I get a TypeError

Tags: python, time, typeerror, callable

***Edit:***
Sorry for not elaborating on this earlier. My function that I pass actually has arguments.

It looks kind of like this:

```
...
time_elapsed = get_running_time(runner(x:int, y:int, z:int, return_values:list))
...
```

I pass a **list** as **return_values** parameter (as a reference) and modify it from inside the "runner()" to retrieve values, if it makes any difference

***End of Edit***

I am new to Python and would be very thankful for your help.

I searched online but couldn't find solution to this.

In short, I have a piece of code in my program that looks like this:

```
def get_running_time(fn: Callable):
    time_start = time.time()
    fn()
    return time.time() - time_start
```

I pass **some_func()** to **get_running_time(fn: Callable)** to retrieve the time it takes to run

But all I get is

```
...line 152, in get_running_time
    fn()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

What should I change in order for this to work?

Comment: we need to see how you are defining/passing fn to get_running_time

Comment: you should be passing the function without parentheses, if you haven't done that already

Comment: Thank you, but it seems like not the case here, I have edited the question to provide needed info that I haven't

Comment: @JordanHyatt I have edited the question, could you please help with this info? Thanks

Comment: does my updated answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in my comment, you need to pass the function without parentheses. To support arguments, you must pass the function as a `lambda` function:

Code:

```
import time

def get_running_time(fn):
    time_start = time.time()
    fn()
    return time.time() - time_start
    
def printer(word):
    for i in range(100):
        print(word)
        
print(get_running_time(lambda: printer("Hello!")))
```

Output:

```
Hello!
...
Hello!
7.414817810058594e-05
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, it could have helped if my fn() had no arguments, but it has, I forgot to mention it, my bad

Comment: @TimKorelov I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you, I am not very familiar with lambdas here, will try to implement and reply as soon as I manage to get it to work

Comment: Yes! It both is simple and working! I just added "lambda: " everywhere where I pass the function and it works now, thank you!

Comment: Ah yes, this solution is essentially doing the same thing as partial.  However, if your arguments get more complex and abundant, lambdas might not be feasible, I would still recommend looking into partials or passing arbitrary args/kwargs

Comment: @JordanHyatt yes, thank you, I looked into it and I found that this is actually essential for programming in this language, will definitely be using now

Answer (score 1):

Based on your last comment.

```
def get_running_time(fn: Callable,*args,**kwargs):
    time_start = time.time()
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return time.time() - time_start

def fn(arg1, arg2, arg3=None):
   time.sleep(3)

arg1=10
arg2=20
get_running_time(fn, arg1, arg2)
```

or using partial

```
from functools import partial

def get_running_time(fn):
    time_start = time.time()
    fn()
    return time.time() - time_start

def fn(arg1, arg2, arg3=None):
   time.sleep(3)

arg1=10
arg2=20
p = partial(fn, arg1, arg2)
get_running_time(p)
```

Comment: I am doing something similar, although not because I am trying to call that function, but because it has arguments that I somehow need to pass to it. I edited the original question

Comment: Oh ok, then your function needs to allow them to be passed.  editing my response

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I need some time to understand it, thanks :D

Comment: No problem, you could also use a partial.....here is the documentation for that https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html

Comment: Thank you!     Also, who thought that minimum char limit for comments was a good idea?...

Comment: If you are anywhere near the comment-size limit, you are probably misusing the comments.